# Better way to chain jquery methods from one parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I always used to write the events starting from one parent (in my case `vehiclesParent`) in a new line, like this, usually for `.find()` functions:

```
 var vehiclesParent = $(this).parents('.services-content.vehicles');
        if (vehiclesParent.length > 0) {
            vehiclesParent.find('.offices-select-copy').val('0').trigger('change').css('margin', '42px 32px 0 0');
            vehiclesParent.find('.copy-now').hide();
            vehiclesParent.find('.cancel-vehicles-tab').css('margin', '-30px 0');
        }
```

there is a better way to reproduce this?

Comment: Better how? What you have seems fine.

Comment: to don't repeat this part `vehiclesParent.find` :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong repeating `cachedElement.find` except if you find an element twice...

Comment: Better way is NOT to use javascript to manipulate styles. You can simply add a corresponding class for most of what you have now.
`vehiclesParent.addClass('someclz')` and in your css `.someclz .copy-now {display: none;} .someclz .office-select-copy {margin: 42px 32px 0 0;} .someclz .cancel-vehicles-tab { margin: -30px 0;}`. Thus you will only need to set value to `.offices-select-copy` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, You're looking for the [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) method, So that you can continue chaining instead of repeatedly using the varable

```
var vehiclesParent = $(this).parents('.services-content.vehicles');
    if (vehiclesParent.length > 0) {
        vehiclesParent.find('.offices-select-copy').val('0').trigger('change').css('margin', '42px 32px 0 0')
       .end().find('.copy-now').hide()
       .end().find('.cancel-vehicles-tab').css('margin', '-30px 0');
    }
```

---

Side note: There is an argument going on regarding variable vs `end()`

I personally use both -

- I use `.end()` when I no longer requires the selection down the line in my code, So that you don't have to introduce a variable.
- I use a variable when I have to use the selection again somewhere else in my code

Using `.end()` while you have already stored the reference in a variable doesn't make much sense.

So in short, use `end()` when you can perform the operation in single line and doesn't need to access the collection later in your code. I usually name jquery variables like `$elements` and I don't like seeing much of them in code.

Comment: I doubt this way is somehow better. :) More symbols, harder to debug.

Comment: Also, additional function calls. It is not faster (or better). Just a (slower) alternative.

Comment: i`m just reading the http://api.jquery.com/end/ and with .end() function the code seems to be more readable but slower.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko OP clearly mentioned *to don't repeat this part vehiclesParent.find* in comments, that means he wants to continue chaining, and this is how you do it in jquery.

Comment: @TJ not arguing about that, your answer is technically right about that. But OP also ask if there is a better way to do that. I doubt there is except if OP has one element in those `.find` which is children of an other one. That's why ill not downvote or upvote your answer. It may still be useful, so keep it up!

Comment: @FinciucSergiu It is in no way slower as far as I know. jQuery object has a stack of matched elements, when you do `find()` a new set is pushed into the stack, when you do `end()` it's popped and we're back to the previous collection. No extra `DOM` traversal is being done. Popping an item from a stack isn't much of an overhead. There is a reason why that method exists in jQury

Comment: @TJ The function itself is not really slow, but the extra function call vs a variable slow the process. Still, we're are talking about milliseconds. Nobody can notice it.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes the OP says *"with .end() function the code seems to be more readable but slower"* - I find this very funny because I can't think of an application that'll instantly become noticeably slower when we introduce a function call O.o maybe you guys scared him :D

Comment: no, i`m not a performance freak :D more like readable freak. howether i like the idea of implementing the end(); Thanks.

Comment: @FinciucSergiu Read my updated answer again, hopefully you'll understand what's the use of `.end()`...

Comment: @TJ Sure. Your answer is technically correct. 
Performance effect of end call is neglectable. Though such a long chains make it harder to debug. :)